# Opening file to image View

Tags: android, image

I want to open file from sdcard i am doing it with this code:

```
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"folder_name/myPicName.jpeg");
    image.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Can someone help me please

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: is this code correct? coz i cant open image

Comment: Make sure there's a `/` before `folder_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder_name/myPicName.jpeg");
image.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Also, need to add File read/write permission in the manifest file (if you need to write to external storage):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Hope it helps.